# Merge vectors to a vector of vectors spark data frame

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, vector, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark data frame with 4 columns. The first three ara vectors and the last one a string. For each row the length of each vector is different. I want to merge the first three into one column named features that will be a Vector of length three and each element will be the vector i described. I tried to use vector assembler, but the result was only one vector. That had as result logistic regression show an error because as i said vectors of each row have a different size. Thanks in advance. Example:

```
Col1 = [1.5,2.3,4.8]
Col2 = [1.2,3.6.1.9,10.5,3.2]
Col3 = [1.4,5.6]
Then feature for first row will be
Feature = [[1.5,2.3,4.8],[1.2,3.6.1.9,10.5,3.2], [1.4,5.6]]
```

Comment: you could use sparse vector if you have different size

Comment: Yes but tried this:
 df2 = df.select(SparseVector(df["N"],df["ind"],df["tfidf"]).allias("features"))
i got TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Column'

Comment: you should try to do this with UDF

Comment: Something like this? :
to_vector = udf(lambda a: SparseVector(a), VectorUDT())
df = df.select(to_vector(df["N"],df["ind"],df["tfidf"]).allias("features"))
?